# Power distribution boards - hierarchical numbering system

Tags: power-engineering

I wish to renumber the circuit breakers (and possibly the cables) in an industrial plant.

- Numbering should give a unique identifier for each breaker.
- Numbering should give a path back to the incoming supply.

[image]

*Figure 1. Part of a power-distribution tree.*

I've had a look at various systems such as [KKP](https://www.vgb.org/en/db_ds_for_pp.html) and its replacement RDS-PP (Reference Designation System for Power Plants) but I'm not sure that either could be used to give the "at-a-glance" hierarchical naming that I want.

Can anyone suggest an expandable numbering system that would identify each circuit breaker in Figure 1? How would the incoming breakers be numbered? How would the panels be numbered?

Comment: Hm, what's wrong with the scheme in Figure 1? If I might extrapolate, the breakers attached to `ETC` would be called `A4-2-1`…`A4-2-5`.

Comment: Figure 1 makes sense to me.  What's the problem?

Comment: You may also want to consider including which phase the circuit is on. Standard here down under is R1, W1, B1, R2, W2, B2 and so on - phases are Red, White, Blue.